# Can't sort a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to sort a list of objects, I searched on the net and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Here is my domain class containing the list that I want to sort :

```
class MyClass {
    Integer bar
    static hasMany = [**foos : Foo**]
}
```

The object Foo look like this :

```
class Foo {
    LocalDate day
    String name
}
```

I want to sort foos by date. So I tried to write :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
//foos contains 10 days.
myClass.foos = myClass.foos.sort { it.day }
```

I don't understand where is the mistake and why my list isn't properly sorted. Can some one help ?

Thanks.

Comment: `myClass.foos.toList().sort{it.day}`

Answer (score 5):

`hasMany` is backed by a `Set` by default. Try changing it to a `List`, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    Integer bar
    List foos
    static hasMany = [foos : Foo]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options how to sort objects by default. Both are inside the sortable class:

1. (for simple sorting alogorithms):

   ```
   static mapping = {
       sort 'dateCreated':'desc'
   }
   ```
2. (for complex sorting algorithms you use a function):

   ```
   class Target implements Comparable {

   ...

       int compareTo(o) {

           if(o instanceof Target) {
               Target t = (Target) o
               // sort multidimensional
               return (this.target_definition_order <=> t.target_definition_order ?:
               this.target_order <=> t.target_order )
           } else
               return 0
       }

   }
   ```

Your problem might be the sorting algorithm of the special class `LocalDate`.

Comment: My class isn't persisted (mapWith = "none") I think that I can't use the sort in the static mapping block. I'm gonna try the method with the compareTo(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided the sort works if you use a Date object instead of LocalDate..

```
        use(TimeCategory) {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(bar: 1)
            Date today = new Date()
            def foo = new Foo(name: "a", day: today)
            myClass.addToFoos(foo)
            myClass.save(flush: true)
            foo = new Foo(name: "a", day: today+1.second)
            myClass.addToFoos(foo)
            foo = new Foo(name: "a", day: today+2.second)
            myClass.addToFoos(foo)
            foo = new Foo(name: "a", day: today+3.second)
            myClass.addToFoos(foo)
            foo = new Foo(name: "a", day: today+4.second)
            myClass.save(flush: true)
        }
```

Using myClass.foos.sort{it.date} or myClass.foos.sort{it.date}.reverse() gives the correct result.